# How to change column charset, set as not null and add a default value?

Tags: mysql, sql

The column contains some rules such as not nullable and character_set_name is latin1 and I should write a query to update **only the character_set_name**.

> field: name
>
> type: varchar(255)
>
> null: NO
>
> default: JACK
>
> character_set_name: latin1

Is there any way to do this in one query?

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'JACK';
```

if I run only the first query, 'name' will accept null values and default=null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, simpy write them together

```
ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'JACK';
```

Comment: thank u!! I was trying to put CHARACTER SET as the last option

Comment: I tried but StackOverflow doesn't allow it and says that I should wait some minutes. I'm waiting and I'll accept it! Thank u